# Facing an error when trying to install rJava in Azure Data Bricks

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks, rjava

Error in dyn.load("/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so")  No such file or directory. Facing this error in Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 2):

It's well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/r/install-rjava-rjdbc-libraries) in the Azure Databricks knowledge base. Because rJava depends on the specific locations, you need to perform some magic with symlinks before installing rJava (this could be done via [init script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/init-scripts) as well):

```
%sh
ls -l /usr/bin/java
ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
R CMD javareconf
```