# Issues Installing RWeka in Databricks

Tags: r, databricks, rweka

I'm trying to install RWeka on DataBricks, using R but keep running into this error:

Error in library(RWeka) : there is no package called ‘RWeka’

This is the code I'm using:

```
install.packages('rJava')
install.packages('RWeka') code here
library(rJava)
library(RWeka)
```

Comment: that could be a problem with rJava: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71925110/facing-an-error-when-trying-to-install-rjava-in-azure-data-bricks/71925335#71925335

Comment: But please add the output of the installation commands - there should be errors there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider something like

```
%sh
ls -l /usr/bin/java
ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
R CMD javareconf

%r
install.packages("rJava")
# dyn.load('/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so')
library(rJava)

install.packages("RWeka")
library(RWeka)
```

The clusters in Databricks are using Linux. See https://kb.databricks.com/r/install-rjava-rjdbc-libraries.html